# How should I handle records not found when dealing with a json method

Tags: c#, web-services

I am using the following web method to get data for a driver my question is however. My question is what is the best way when your returning json to handle an error if data is not found is their a specific error code like page not found i no is 404 that i should send back in my webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
public motorista GetDriverInformation(int driverId)
{

        motorista _wsmoristita = new motorista();
        _wsmoristita = _dal.GetDriverInformation(driverId);
        return _wsmoristita;          

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using **jquery ajax**. You can throw custom exception in the `WebMethod` with specific message, and after that in error function which you define in the ajax call you will show this message.

Part of `$.ajax({});`

```
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnErrorCall
```

Your `OnErrorCall` function will look like this

```
 function OnErrorCall(response) {

     alert(response.responseText);
  }
```

You can even show the message in some textbox, so if you throw an exception with text **Record is not found** or something like that, you can show it in label,alert or etc.

Here is an example of custom exception. You can read [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want

```
public class EmployeeListNotFoundException: Exception
{
    public EmployeeListNotFoundException()
    {
    }

    public EmployeeListNotFoundException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public EmployeeListNotFoundException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like below but I persume its not the best way as its to genral and wouldnt idnetify the column causing the fault to the web developer.

```
if (_wsHistory.id_terminal == 0)
 {

            Context.Response.Status = "404 Terminal table Not Found";
            //the next line is untested - thanks to strider for this line
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            //the next line can result in a ThreadAbortException
            //Context.Response.End(); 
            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            return null;
}
```